# Is it possible to create marker with animated icon?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm using Google Maps SDK for iOS and I would like to display a marker on my map. I've found out that the class `GMSMarker` is involved but it only accepts `UIImage` icon.

I would like the icon to be `UIView` or `CALayer` such that its contents could be animated. Is this possible?

I know that if needed, both of the aforementioned UI objects can be rendered into `UIImage`. However, that's utterly unefficient and ugly code. I would be really happy if there was other way.

Thanks in advance,
Pete.

Answer (score 0):

No, the marker (or overlay) can only display UIImage objects, although they do support animated UIImages (see the AnimatedCurrentLocationViewController in the demo project).